# React native - Edit pdf by having users type in text field

Tags: android, react-native, pdf

I am using react native to rebuild an android app similar to Adobe Fill & Sign.
The problem is, i don’t know how to let users tap on the pdf, render a text field on top of a pdf where users tap, and have users type inside it.

Anyone has any idea how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My idea would be to place a transparent view placed over the pdf view, which will trigger the dialog opening, like i trigger below the alert. Your dialog will contain the TextInput that you want:
(You can calculate x and y coordinates of user press, and then fire dialog in that place of view to get what you want)

```
<View>
    <View> {/* this view will be the pdf*/}
      <Text>{"backgroundView_place of pdf for example"}</Text>
      <Text>{"More pdf texts"}</Text>
    </View>
 {/* this view will be over the pdf and onClick some dialog with input will be triggered, i use alert for example*/}
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback
      onPress={() => {
        alert("InputDialog will be opened here");
      }}
    >
      <View
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          height: 600,
          width: 300,
          backgroundColor: "transparent"
        }}
      />
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
</View>
```

You can use [react-native-dialog](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dialog) or any other dialog library that lets you add TextInput or any component you wish inside it.
*Note:* I use TouchableWithoutFeedback so that no effect happen on click, like change of opacity or highlight etc.

Comment: this is a good idea, but how to combine pdf and text that user entered in one pdf ?

Comment: any progress so far? if so please let me know

Comment: @Kholiavko I would take screenshot of the view using [react-native-view-shot](https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot) and then create a pdf with that image using [pdf-lib](https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib)